# App crashes when bringing the app to foreground while playing high memory games

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

I have a wiered problem with my app.

When I bring my app to foreground from background while playing high memory consuming games like Asphalt 8, the app crashes. **This happens only when I play high memory app like Asphalt 8**.The crashing is occuring because the activity context becomes null.

I have no idea on how to fix this. Is there anyone who knows a solution on how to fix this.

Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE**

**Logcat:**

```
  7927-7927/com.xxxxx.android.beta E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.xxxxxx.android.beta, PID: 7927
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxx.android.beta/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.Login.InitialScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.xxxxxxxx.android.Login.SwipeFragment_Second.onCreateView(SwipeFragment_Second.java:42)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1917)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:544)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1243)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5969)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
03-17 13:38:48.531    7927-7954/com.xxxxxxxxx.android.beta I/Fabric﹕ Crashlytics report upload complete:
```

Comment: please post the logcat and if possible relevant part of code, without seeing any stacktrace we cannot help....

Comment: @Opiatefuchs This is the common error that is shown in logcat. Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: In the above case getSystemService is using null object refernece.

Comment: ok, I know this error, but I need to see the relevant code which is causing this error, maybe we can fix it...

Comment: Please add a full logcat like Opiatefuchs suggested, not just a one-liner. There might be interesting stuff further back in the log.

Does it happen also if closing your app and restarting it, or only when resuming from background?

What device? How much RAM?

Comment: The app works fine without any problem except when I bring it to foreground while playing high memory apps like asphalt 8. It is happening everywhere in the app. In some cases getsupportactionbar() returns null.

Comment: It only happens when running high memory utilising apps.

Comment: I am testing this on Moto G 2nd Gen(Lollipop).

Comment: I've posted the logcat.

Comment: When you run another app that requires a lot of memory, Android will kill your app if it is in the background. When you then try to bring your app to the foreground, Android will create a new process for your app and reinstantiate ONLY the top `Activity` on the stack. If that `Activity` is relying on variables or state being set up in other, previous, activities, then you will see this kind of behaviour. Where is the context variable being initialized that is used in `SwipeFragment_Second` line 42?

Comment: @DavidWasser context is initialised inside constructor of fragment.

Comment: Please post that code.

Comment: @DavidWasser Sir, I am getting the error everywhere in the places where I use fragment. The common thing I've seen in every place is activity context is getting null.

Comment: Yes, please post the code you use to set the context in your `Fragment`. You are obviously doing this wrong!.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? Or is this still an issue? If so, please post the code I requested.

Comment: @DavidWasser  Fixed it(not by myself). Removed passing context and used get activity() instead. Your explanation was helpful.

Comment: As I said, you aren't passing the `Context` into your `Fragment` properly. Glad you solved it. Could you post an answer so this question gets off the unanswered list please?